# set php session on only www.website.tld and www.apps.website.tld

Tags: php, session, cookies

I only want the session cookie on www.website.tld and www.apps.website.tld, using ini_set if possible. Also i need to set all cookies i write to both subdomains only. I do not want www.imgs.website.tld to have the cookies. the php session one i'm kinda unsure of. The cookies i set my self my idea was to call SetBothCookie($name,$value,$time) a custom function.

```
function SetBothCookie($name,$value,$time)
{
setcookie($name, $value, $time, "", "www.website.tld", 1);
setcookie($name, $value, $time, "", "www.apps.website.tld", 1);
}
```

So i think i have the SetBothCookie part down, but wanted to see what others think of that code. The part i'm stuck on is having php set the session cookie on both sub domains. I'm using `session_set_save_handler` to override the default php session storage to store sessions in the database, so both servers can use the same session data. From my understanding is if i put Javascript that does http requests on the www.apps.website.tld to www.website.tld it won't allow them to happen, and i want that added security, so thats my reason of running only a part of the site on a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work but...

Using `secure` parameter in [set_cookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) according to PHP manual

> Indicates that the cookie should only
>   be transmitted over a secure HTTPS
>   connection from the client. When set
>   to TRUE, **the cookie will only be set
>   if a secure connection exists.** On the
>   server-side, it's on the programmer to
>   send this kind of cookie only on
>   secure connection (e.g. with respect
>   to $_SERVER["HTTPS"]).

So I suggest to remove 6th parameter of set_cookie() function.

Also, you can call this function before any output or it will throw a warning like

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at ...) in ... on line XX

Using [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) is good solution to take control over session variables.

If you want cookies for entire domain just use `"/"` or `".website.tld"` (with initial dot according to [RFC 2109](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2109.html) standard) for `domain` parameter (5th in a row). Parameter `path` should be `""` (empty string; 4th).

Comment: I wrap the website in ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); It fixes the header errors for me.